# Winform application Timer doesn´t work correctly

Tags: c#, winforms, timer

i´m doing a winform app, and the timer isn´t working fine. First time works, and then, it doesn´t.
Here is the code:

```
public void GetNewTurn(Turn turn)
{
    _tmrStarTime = DateTime.Now;
    timer1.Start();
    timer1.Tick += tmr1_Tick;
}

private void tmr1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //timer code here
    timer.stop();
}
```

So, the idea is:
GetNewTurn is a function which is invoked from another place. The first time which I invoke it, works fine, then doesn´t. I put a breakpoint inside the tmr1_Tick, and i can see that it just works the first time, then, doesn´t.
In the Timer properties, i set Enable = True.
What i´m doing wrong?
Thanks!

Comment: It appears that you are *stopping* the timer after the first tick... so I would expect that to only run once.

Comment: Umm..you are stopping it. So why would it continue to run after you stop it? If you want it to keep going, remove your `timer.stop();`.

Comment: from the code I see above I would suggest that you use a process it can be triggered independently and stop independently and you can create more than one process every time you call the method GetNewTurn

Comment: @Icemanind i stop it after 2 seconds, then, when the GetNewTurn fuction is invoked again, it should start again..

Answer (score 3):

You shoudn't stop the tmr1_Tick in the first tick

```
public void GetNewTurn(Turn turn)
{
    _tmrStarTime = DateTime.Now;
    timer1.Start();
    timer1.Tick += tmr1_Tick;
}

private void tmr1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //the code for each tick 
}
```

Comment: I don´t, i stop it after 2 seconds (I didn´t write all the code..)

Answer (score 3):

Only add the handler once in the constructor or OnLoad override.

```
timer1.Tick += tmr1_Tick;

public void GetNewTurn(Turn turn)
{
  _tmrStarTime = DateTime.Now;
  timer1.Start();
}
```

Comment: Nice, for the proper way of doing things, but it wouldn't solve his problem.

Comment: @Verdolino I'm guessing it does because he probably had multiple calls happening to the Tick method.  It's not the stopping the timer that's the issue, it's whatever the OP was doing in the "timer code here" part.  My guess.

Comment: If i put the handler in the constructor, when i open the form, it automatically start the timer.. and i don´t wanna it.

Comment: @MatiSilver Then make sure the timer is disabled from the designer.